# Redirect loop when accessing wp-admin, working as subdirectory to other CMS system

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm facing problem with redirect loop when I'm trying to access wp-admin in wordpress site configured as subdirectory to other CMS.

Every other site is working fine, even wp-login.php. It logs me successfully (I can see logged user bar at the top of the site), but still, wp-admin gives me redirect loop. When I'm trying to reach wp-admin/index.php directly, it redirects me to wp-login.php, allows me to pass my credentials, then returns 403 error.

It keeps redirect me this way:

```
https://www.mycms.pl/my/wp/wp-admin/
302: Temporary redirect to https://www.mycms.pl/my/wp/wp-admin/
```

I'm pasting my nginx config below.

Directories are:

Other CMS: `/srv/my-cms/production/current`

wordpress: `/srv/wordpress/my/wp`

and vhost config:

```
server {

        listen 80 http2;

        server_name mycms.pl www.mycms.pl;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/mycms_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mycms_error.log error;

        return 301 https://www.mycms.pl$request_uri;


}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        server_name mycms.pl www.mycms.pl;

        root /srv/mycms.pl/production/current;

        index index.php;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/mycms_access.log combined;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mycms_error.log error;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/przekierowania_if.params;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/apps/mycms.pl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/apps/mycms.pl/server.key;

        if ($http_host != "www.mycms.pl") {
                 rewrite ^ https://www.mycms.pl$request_uri permanent;
        }



################ wordpress my-wp ###
        rewrite ^/wp-content/(.*?)$ /my/wp/wp-content/$1 last;


location /my/wp {
                try_files $uri /my/wp/index.php?$args;
                root /srv/wordpress;
                location ~* \.(css|gif|jpg|js|png|ico|otf|sng|xls|doc|exe|jpeg|tgx|ttf)$ {
                        access_log off;
                        expires max;
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                }
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 128k;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/wp-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                }
        }
################


        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        client_max_body_size 500m;

        location ~* \.(css|gif|jpg|js|png|ico|otf|sng|xls|doc|exe|jpeg|tgx|ttf)$ {
                access_log off;
                expires max;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location /admin {

                deny all;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/mycms-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                        fastcgi_cache if_cache;
                        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
                }
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                fastcgi_cache if_cache;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
                fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/mycms-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

If you could please help me, cuz I've already wasted few days fighting this....

Thank you very much from advance!